# How to change word to specific word?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to change words for example I have a text:

"hello"

and i need to change it to:

"ჰელლო"

How can i detect if text contains for example char "h" and then change it to char "ჰ" ?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace method:

```js
var str = "hello";

var newStr = str.replace("h", "Y");

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want.

If you want to detect just `hello` you can use a simple `replace()`:

```
let str = 'hello, how are you?'

let newStr = str.replace('hello', 'ჰელლო')

console.log(newStr) // Output: 'ჰელლო, how are you?'
```

If you need just to detect the first letter `h` you can do the same:

```
let str = 'hello, how are you?'

let newStr = str.replace('h', 'ჰ')

console.log(newStr) // Output: 'ჰello, how are you?'
```

But if you want to detect all letters `h` you must use `RegExp`

```
let str = 'hello, how are you?'

let newStr = str.replace(/h/g, 'ჰ')

console.log(newStr) // Output: 'ჰello, ჰow are you?'
```